# place message text right of actor in PlantUML sequence diagram

Tags: uml, graphviz, sequence-diagram, plantuml

**BACKGROUND**

An UML sequence diagram is commonly used to create a representation of messages sent between actors of a system, and thus clarifying the information flow. In general, messages are displayed `between` the communicating actors, which is a good practice and obviously appropriate for handling "messages".

**MY APPLICATION**

Now, I want to (mis)use sequence diagrams rather for clarifying which `activity` is performed on which actor, rather than which `messages` are sent between actors. Thus, I can e.g. describe the activity distribution within my system. I want to place text describing activities `on the right` of actors.

**MY PROBLEM**

When handling "Notes" in activity diagrams, PlantUML provides the possibility to freely place them around (left, right or in the center) of an actor, but I haven't figured out if this freedom was granted to messages as well.

Here is an example PlantUML sequence:

```
@startuml

' two activities executed on actor1

activate "actor1" #Olive
"actor1" -> "actor1": actor1 activity1\nactor1 summary1

' two sub-activities  executed on actor1

activate "actor1" #OliveDrab
"actor1" -> "actor2": actor1 sub-activity1\nactor1 sub-activity2

' then comes a transition from actor1 to actor2
' and two activities executed on actor2

activate "actor2" #Olive
"actor2" -> "actor1": actor2 func activity1\nactor2 func activity2

' two sub-activities executed on actor2

activate "actor2" #OliveDrab
"actor2" -> "actor2": actor2 func sub-activity1

@enduml
```

Which creates this result:

[image: created by the PlantUML script above]

Currently, the diagram has some other problems as well, but that shouldn't be an issue, here. I would just like to be able to place the "messages", which should be thought of "activities" in my case, on the right of each of the actors where they are created / initiated.

Here a principle picture how I could imagine the output:

[image]

I could try to use messages going from e.g. "actor2" to "actor2", but this always creates these reflexive arrows, which I don't really want to be seen in the diagram. And, I would like to stick to PlantUML for these kind of diagrams. Don't know if there was another kind of diagram to display "actors" and their "activities" in relation to each other.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Hello did you try using https://plantuml.com/en/timing-diagram as an alternate way for representing activities?

Comment: thanks for the hint. I think timing diagrams might be too far off the style I have in mind for my application. but I will have a detailled look at them in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always hide the arrows using white transparent color and create some "fake activations" It is a bit of a hack but I guess this would suite your request:

```
@startuml
A1 -[#ffffff00]> A1: 
activate A1
A1 -[#ffffff00]> A1: first activity of A1
A2 -[#ffffff00]> A2: 
activate A2
A2 -[#ffffff00]> A2: first activity of A2
A1 -[#ffffff00]> A1: 
activate A1 #blue
A1 -[#ffffff00]> A1: 2nd activity of A1
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: I see some artifacts here in the form of the "breaking" of the shadow, so possibly best to set `skinparam shadowing false` as well, but I still see some "breaking" of the bars. Doing some further experiments, best is to use a color like `#ffffff00` where the transparency part is set.

Comment: @albert. Good Idea: I fixed my answer, it is quite better this way. Thx